# C# generic function applicable on Linq objects in a json server application

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework, linq

I need to execute CRUD operations on LINQ objects from a customized JSON command in a web server application written in C#.
For instance, I receive a select command and I produce a JSON dataset; next my web rich client produces a customized json command for a transaction that I need to execute on server database.
I cannot change json client format so I can't use WebApi.
I receive a structured json where I receive some data and operation required (for instance, Insert).
I would like to write a generic method that receive the operation and 
data and execute right Linq Object save command.

```
public genericInsert(<T> linqObj, string opJsonRequired) {
    linqObj.LoadFromJson(opJsonRequired);
    linqObj.save(dbContext);
}
```

I would like to write the SpecificInsert (update, delete) method in the  partial class generated by visual studio.
Can you point in the correct and productive way to do this in C# (I'm using MS VS2010). I tryed with delegate without success.

Comment: Could you provide a JSON Example?

Comment: I receive in a POST request a json structure with 4 elements, one of them indicate CRUD operation, one is a conventional TableName and 2 are table record before and after modify. I haven't problem in deserialize and serialize with Json.net tools. My problem is centralize management of input json and call right Linq object containing record data...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for an extension method with a deserializer

```
public genericInsert<T>(T linqObj, string opJsonRequired) {
     linqObj.LoadFromJson(opJsonRequired);
     linqObj.save(dbContext);
}

public static class LinqObjectExtensions 
{
   public static T LoadFromJson(this T source, string opJsonRequired) where T : 'SomeType' {
       JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
       var operation = ('SomeType')serializer.Deserialize(opJsonRequired);
       ...do operation to T  
       return T;
}
```